# Specify a preferred pypi server, with fallback to standard one

Tags: python, pip

I would like to specify, for a single project (neither globally for the user, nor system wide), a preferred pypi server. This should be used to request packages, and if the packages are not found, the standard pypi server should be used.

In `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`, I put the following content:

```
[global]
index-url = http://my-server:31337/simple
```

My questions are:

- is this the right way to specify a per-project pip.conf? Does it really need to be in the venv? I would prefer to have in the cwd. Simply because the venv is not part of my repo, but the cwd is. If I need it to be in the venv, it means *every user* must install a copy of the `pip.conf` in the venv, which is a pita (I do not know nor care were the users are keeping their venvs, and I do not even want to write a setup guide for this)
- by specifying `index-url`, am I specifying a preferred server, or an exclusive server? I still would like the standard pypi to be reachable by pip.

And just out of curiosity:

- *if* this is just a preferred server (good for my use case!), how would I specify an exclusive server?
- is it possible to specify more than one `index-url`?
- what would be the `index-url` for the standard `pypi`?